# Passing file location through main?

Tags: c++, g++

I am building a web application / Interface for my C++ program which will be hosted on the server and then using a scripting language ("PHP") I will then execute the program to run.

I am using G++ to compile the code and and I execute the command to run like so: ("./main") now is it possible that I can pass in the file location so then my program can run? So for example like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], string* fileLoc)
{
    // code

}
```

Then execute like this ("./main(FILE_LOCATION)")?

Hope someone can help

Comment: You most likely need a command line argument. That's what the first two parameters are for. For the record, an implementation accepting that signature is non-conforming.

Comment: You seem to be confusing program execution from shell with C++ function calls. The two are largely unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep the standard `main` signature `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. The filename would be in `argv[1]`, provided you execute it like this:

> ./main somefilename.txt

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1)
    std::cout << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

> ./main Hello_there
>
> Hello_there

Comment: which is a char array, right? Ok, I'll give that a go, thank you :)!

Comment: @Phorce `argv` is an array of `char*`, which usually are null-terminated strings. The first argument, `arg[0]`, is the name of the executable itself.